# com.rnfs.RNFSManager.mkdir: java.lang.Exception: Directory could not be created

Tags: android, react-native

https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs

### code

```js
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

RNFS.mkdir(RNFS.ExternalDirectoryPath + dir)
```

### logcat

```
05-06 22:43:41.693  W/System.err: java.lang.Exception: Directory could not be created
05-06 22:43:41.697  W/System.err:     at com.rnfs.RNFSManager.mkdir(RNFSManager.java:680)
```

This error occurs after compilation，

But it is normal when debugging，

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, permission

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```